# Removing Gap from Image using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1

I have two ortho images with having gap due to inproper cutting of images its overlay.

How to remove this gap in ArcMap 10.1?

[image]

Comment: How precisely did the gap get there?  Maybe you can prevent it arising?  If it is not preventable then what precisely have you tried in order to remove it?  I note that you have been using this site for 2 months but have not yet taken its 2-minute [Tour] that is designed to introduce all users to its protocols.

Comment: Actually this is not real gap this image cut not properly so due to unpropper cutting image is overlay to eachother

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any necessary clarifications.